# TwitchAPI Get streams and filter them by specific stream tag

Tags: javascript, next.js, twitch-api

So I'm struggling with TwitchAPI because their API is quite limited with filtering what you are trying to query from them. So I'm using [GetStreams](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/api/reference/#get-streams) from TwitchAPI, but unfortunately with said query you can't specify tags as parameter, so I have been working on a "work around".

Here is my `/pages/api/twitch.js` in my next.js application:

```js
const { TWITCH_CLIENT_ID, TWITCH_CLIENT_SECRET } = process.env;

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  //console.log(req.query.tag)
  try {
    const tokenUrl = `https://id.twitch.tv/oauth2/token`;
    const tokenData = new URLSearchParams({
      client_id: TWITCH_CLIENT_ID,
      client_secret: TWITCH_CLIENT_SECRET,
      grant_type: 'client_credentials',
    });

    const tokenResponse = await fetch(tokenUrl, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      },
      body: tokenData,
    });

    const tokenJson = await tokenResponse.json();
    const accessToken = tokenJson.access_token;

    const tag = req.query.tag; // Assuming you pass the tag as a query parameter

    const limit = 12; // Number of streams per page
    let cursor = null; // Initialize the cursor to null
    let fetchedStreams = 0; // Number of streams fetched so far
    const fetchedCursors = []

    // Array to store all fetched streams
    let allStreams = [];

    // Fetch streams with pagination until we reach the desired limit
    while (fetchedStreams < limit) {
      if (cursor && fetchedCursors.includes(cursor)) {
        // Skip fetching this cursor again
        break;
      }
      let twitchUrl = `https://api.twitch.tv/helix/streams?first=${limit - fetchedStreams}&language=en`;
      if (cursor) {
        twitchUrl += `&after=${cursor}`;
      }

      const twitchResponse = await fetch(twitchUrl, {
        headers: {
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
          'Client-ID': TWITCH_CLIENT_ID,
        },
      });

      const twitchJson = await twitchResponse.json();

      // Check if the response contains any streams
      if (twitchJson.data.length === 0) {
        break; // No more streams to fetch, exit the loop
      }

      // Filter the fetched streams to include only streams with the desired tag
      const streamsWithTag = twitchJson.data.filter(stream => {
        return Array.isArray(stream.tags) && stream.tags.includes(tag);
      });

      // Add the filtered streams to the 'allStreams' array
      allStreams = allStreams.concat(streamsWithTag);

      // Update the fetchedStreams count
      fetchedStreams += streamsWithTag.length;

      if (cursor) {
        fetchedCursors.push(cursor);
      }
      // Update the cursor to fetch the next page
      cursor = twitchJson.pagination.cursor;
      //console.log(fetchedCursors)
      //console.log(allStreams.length)
    }
                                                
    const finalStreams = allStreams.slice(0, limit);
    //console.log(streams);

    res.status(200).json(finalStreams);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching Twitch data:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal server error' });
  }
}
```

So it basically queries TwitchAPI for as long as it finally finds enough streams with specific tag. Now the issue is that it takes way too long to go through all the streams, and also sometimes gives me old `cursor` values, so it can be looping for hours before I get any streams, with addition for it to take too long, I'm pretty sure Twitch will ratelimit me before I get what I want from them.

Is there any way I can improve this to make actually take less time, or am I doomed to wait till Twitch decides to improve their API.